# Angular 6 и Yandex Map API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, angular6

хочу в темплейте у балуна карты вызвать (click)="open()"
но метод open не вызывается. В чем причина?

```
             balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div><button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="exampleModal" onclick="this.open();">Click</button></div>'

  open() {
    console.log('test2');
  }
```

Comment: Потому что `this` в `onclick` ссылается на инстанс класса `HTMLButtonElement`, а не на инстанс компонента

Comment: Спасибо за совет! А как мне тогда сделать чтобы ссылался на компонент?

Answer (score -2):

1. вам нужно назначить `mainClass`.

   var mainClass = this;
2. не выполняется потому что необходимо прописать : `onclick="function(){mainClass.open();};"`
3. выполнять создание блока в строку не рекомендуется. вот небольшой пример как это надо делать:

   ```
       var mainClass = this;

       if (!$('#modal-overlay').length) {
           var overlay = $('<div>', {id: 'modal-overlay'});
           overlay.addClass('modal-overlay');
           overlay.addClass('closed');
           overlay.click(function() {mainClass.save();});
           $('body').append(overlay);
       }
   ```

   Это кусок из моего кода. Думаю вы сможете разобраться как нужно строить блоки.

Comment: Что это за бред вообще если указан тег `angular6`?